# IBM: Add a workflow extension in TIM/SIM

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I make my first workflow extension today, and the result isn't really good ! :)

I have this error : 
CTGIMA411E The sendResult( workflow extension method in the com.orange.tiger.itim.extension.workflow.ResultCallback class cannot be processed.

And the trace.log file: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orange.tiger.itim.extension.workflow.ResultCallback

Here this my java code :

```
package com.orange.tiger.itim.extension.workflow;
//my import

public class ResultCallback implements WorkflowApplication {
private WorkflowExecutionContext context;
private WorkflowProcessEntity processEntity;


public void setContext() {
    this.context = null;
}

@Override
public void setContext(WorkflowExecutionContext context) {
        //code
}
}
```

I modify the xml file:

```
    <ACTIVITY ACTIVITYID="sendResult" LIMIT="600000">
        <IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE>
            <APPLICATION CLASS_NAME="com.orange.tiger.itim.extension.workflow.ResultCallback" METHOD_NAME="sendResult" />
            </IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE>
            <TRANSITION_RESTRICTION SPLIT="XOR" />
            <PARAMETERS>
                <IN_PARAMETERS PARAM_ID="summary"      TYPE="String" />
                <IN_PARAMETERS PARAM_ID="description"      TYPE="String" />
            </PARAMETERS>
         <SCRIPT EVENT="onComplete">
         <![CDATA[WorkflowRuntimeContext.setProcessResult(WorkflowRuntimeContext.getActivityResult());
WorkflowRuntimeContext.setProcessResultDetail(WorkflowRuntimeContext.getActivityResultDetail()); ]]>
        </SCRIPT>
    </ACTIVITY>
```

I add my jar in /opt/application/tgrtim/products/itim/lib/.

And finally I restart TIM via NDM console.

Maybe I missed something ? Or I did something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found, I forgot to modify a xml file : 
/opt/websphere/7.0/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/udgis116Cell01/libraries.xml

And add this line : < classPath>${ITIM_HOME}/lib/result-callback.jar< /classPath>

Answer (score 0):

You can also add result-callback.jar directly on Websphere under Environment -> Shared Libraries -> ITIM_LIB -> ${ITIM_HOME}/lib/result-callback.jar